# Job name is not returning correctly in queue.add() in Bull and Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, task-queue, bull

I am trying out add queue for several asynchronous requests. And I added few queues properly, but one issue is not clear to me,
On adding new job by queuename.add(someDATA) the response is giving the job name "default"

Here you can replicate my code,

```
const Queue = require('bull');
const { s3Uploadv3SingleFile, s3Client } = require("../../Aws/s3.js");
const File = require('../../models/fileSchema.js');

const enumUploadVideoQueue = 'uploadVideoQueue'

const uploadVideoQueue = new Queue(enumUploadVideoQueue, {
    redis: {
        port: process.env.REDIS_PORT,
        host: process.env.REDIS_HOST,
        password: process.env.REDIS_PASSWORD 
    },
  defaultJobOptions: {
    removeOnComplete: true,
    removeOnFail: false,
  },
  limiter: {
    max: 10, // process a maximum of 10 jobs at a time
    duration: 5000, // wait for 5 seconds before processing more jobs
  },
})

uploadVideoQueue.process(async (job, done) => {
  // ...logic for uploading video
});


module.exports = {
  enumUploadVideoQueue,
  uploadVideoQueue
}
```

in my video.controller.js

```
  const fileInfo = {...  }
        const fileStream = req.file; // Access the file stream
        // Process the file stream using Bull 


         const queueName = uploadVideoQueue.name;
            console.log({queueName}); // uploadVideoQueue


       const myJob = await uploadVideoQueue.add({ fileStream, fileInfo });
       res.json({status: true, message: "Upload started", job: myJob})
```

but in response the job.name is ****default****.

[image]

One more thing i tried,
I tried to give the name to the queue again by
const myJob = await uploadVideoQueue.add(enumUploadVideoQueue, { fileStream, fileInfo });
but it gives error like Implemented: A header you provided implies functionality that is not implemented

Bull version
"^4.10.4",

Additional information
Node: 18